# How to access todos in another controller rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to learn RoR by creating an application, however, I have come across a problem and I'm not sure if my method is flawed or if it's the correct way to do it but I'm going about it slightly wrong. I think it has something to do with the variable being an instance variable and it's not called in my other controller but I'm not sure how to get it there?

Anyway the problem is -

I have a todos controller, models, views etc. set up via the scaffolding in Rails but I want to be able to display the todos to each user in their 'dashboard' so to speak when they log in. Therefore I assume I need the todos to be in the dashboard controller too, right?

Here's my dashboard controller

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @todos = current_user.todos
  end
end
```

Here I'm calling my todos but they aren't showing when I call them in the view.

and my todos scaffold

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /todos
  # GET /todos.json
  def index
    @todos = current_user.todos
  end

  # GET /todos/1
  # GET /todos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /todos/new
  def new
    @todo = Todo.new
  end

  # GET /todos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /todos
  # POST /todos.json
  def create
    @todo = current_user.todos.new(todo_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /todos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /todos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.update(todo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todo }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /todos/1
  # DELETE /todos/1.json
  def destroy
    @todo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to todos_url, notice: 'Todo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_todo
      @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def todo_params
      params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :item)
    end
end
```

How would I go about displaying my todo items in the dashboard?

Thanks for any help

Comment: `current_user` should return the user who is currently logged in. Does the `current_user` available to `DashboardController` ?

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not 100% sure -- how can I check that? Sorry if stupid question but it's my first project

Comment: `before_action :authenticate_user!` - Add this to your `DashboardController`  like you have in `TodosController`

Comment: Ahh, perfect that works now -- thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

to `DashboardController` like the way you have it in `TodosController` .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a current user in the dashboard controller? You will need to decide how to handle that - either require sign in, or use an if else statement e.g.

```
def home
  if current_user
    @todos = current_user.todos
  end
end
```

Comment: I have done a before_action :authenticate_user! to handle this in the todos.rb file and the user also has to be logged in to visit the dashboard otherwise is redirected to the homepage, is this a correct way of going around it?